# Count relationships by types in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have many relationship types in the database. How do I count relationships by each type without using `apoc`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Solution

```
MATCH ()-[relationship]->() 
RETURN TYPE(relationship) AS type, COUNT(relationship) AS amount
ORDER BY amount DESC;
```

The first line specifies the pattern to define the relationship variable, which is used to determine type and amount in line two.

### Example result

```
╒══════════════╤════════╕
│"type"        │"amount"│
╞══════════════╪════════╡
│"BELONGS_TO"  │1234567 │
├──────────────┼────────┤
│"CONTAINS"    │432552  │
├──────────────┼────────┤
│"IS_PART_OF"  │947227  │
├──────────────┼────────┤
│"HOLDS"       │4       │
└──────────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: You should add `ORDER BY xyz DESC`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It is fine unless you have duplicated relationship names between different nodes and you'd like to catch that. In such a case the following expression might be helpful:
`match (a)-[r]-(b) 
return distinct labels(a), labels(b), type(r) as type, count(r) as amount`

Comment: You should also specify the direction, otherwise directed edges are counted twice: `MATCH ()-[relationship]->()`

Comment: GuyCoder, @FrancescoBoi Thanks for your advice. Solution updated.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a built in procedure in 3.5.x that you can use to retrieve counts, but it does take a bit of filtering to get down to those you are interested in:

```
CALL db.stats.retrieve('GRAPH COUNTS') YIELD data
UNWIND [data IN data.relationships WHERE NOT exists(data.startLabel) AND NOT exists(data.endLabel)] as relCount
RETURN coalesce(relCount.relationshipType, 'all') as relationshipType, relCount.count as count
```